# Execute command when user interaction is detected ( ex: moving mouse, pressing key )

Tags: linux, shell-script, xorg, input

I am trying to make a bash script to turn down the brightness to lowest when idle for a certain amount of time but reverts back to its previous brightness when it detects user interaction whether it be from the mouse or the keyboard.
I know how to do the first part using xautolock but do not know how to execute the second part.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, you know about `xset dpms` which provides power management of the display, and [brightd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/brightd.1.html) which does progressive backlight changes, but if these don't suffice you can detect movement once you are in idle mode by using `xinput` as follows.

List the input devices with simply `xinput` and find the ids of the mouse and keyboard you want to listen to. In my case it was 11 and 9.

```
Logitech USB Optical Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
HID 05f3:0007                            id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

You can then wait for any output from `xinput --test` on each id:

```
xinput --test 9 | read stuff &  pid1=$!
xinput --test 11 | read stuff & pid2=$!
wait -n
kill -hup $pid1 $pid2 2>/dev/null
echo 'ready'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [dbus](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/).  Specifically, use [`dbus-send`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-send.1.html) to invoke the `GetSessionIdleTime` method on `org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver`:

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver --type=method_call --print-reply=literal /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetSessionIdleTime
```

This will print out 4 spaces, then "uint32", then the number of milliseconds since the last time the user pressed a key or moved the mouse.  You can extract the number using the [`cut`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) command:

```
echo $result | cut -d ' ' -f 5
```

This requires [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) `dbus` at regular intervals, so there will be a delay between user input and your script's response, depending on how often you poll.