# How to detect if the computer is idle?

Tags: scripting, linux-mint, services, screenshot

I'm using Linux Mint,
and I run the below service with system start up to0 take automatically screenshots, 
**but I need it to stop taking screenshots if the computer is idle, and run again when it is active**(for example, the mouse is moved). How can this be accomplished?

```
while true; do
  scrot -d 70 '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.jpg' -e 'mv $f 
~/TMP/TempScreenShots'
done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Execute command when user interaction is detected ( ex: moving mouse, pressing key )](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/290058)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute command when user interaction is detected ( ex: moving mouse, pressing key )](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290058/execute-command-when-user-interaction-is-detected-ex-moving-mouse-pressing-k)

Answer (score 6):

Use `xprintidle`:

> xprintidle is a utility that queries the X server for the user's idle
>   time and prints it to stdout (in milliseconds).

```
while :; do
    [ $(xprintidle) -lt 10000 ] && echo do_something
    sleep 3;
done
```

This will echo `do_something` every 3 seconds if last keyboard or mouse activity was less than 10 seconds ago.

---

You might need to install it, e.g.:

```
sudo apt install xprintidle
```

or build it yourself from [source](https://github.com/g0hl1n/xprintidle).

Comment: should i replace  do_something  with my service ? sorry because i'm new in Linux

Comment: Put your command after `&&`